# Developing directly inside a container

Tags: docker, ide, containers, tooling

I have been exploring Docker and containers recently and wanted to know if it is possible to develop directly inside a container? If yes, what are the existing tools?

An example workflow would be:

> Suppose I need Java8, Solr, and MySQL for my project. I create a container with all three of those components. Then, I create the project inside the container and develop there directly – somewhat similar to a virtual machine but, a scaled-down version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using **vscode,** you can now **develop inside a container**.

Now there is a new awesome feature in vscode, this feature allows us to connect us to our containers, in fact, we can install vscode extensions in the container, open the terminal in the container and even debug remotely.

You can read more about it in the next article "**Developing inside a Container**" https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers

Answer (score 3):

Generally you do not develop “inside a container” you just mount the directory with the source code as a volume inside the container. So when you change/build your code that gets synced to the Docker container where the runtime runs it.